# mobileSetKeyboardType "decimal"

Tags: android, livecode

I have a problem on my app in android. I added a code mobileSetKeyboardType "decimal" to show the decimal keyboard to input an amount. But it seems the Dot (".") button, does not work in phone. Works fine in tablet. I tried removing all pKey validations for the amount field but still the same. Anyone have experienced this one on real device? And how did you solve it?

By the way, I added the mobileSetKeyboardType "decimal" on preopencard

Note: I am using Livecode.

Comment: Do you mean that it doesn't work on an emulated phone? Are you using the default Android emulator? Which version of the Android SDK do you have installed? Which version of Android do you use in the emulator?

Comment: @Mark I am using a real device. Android Version 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer because that allows me to include a formatted script.

What happens if you put the following handler into the field script:

```
on rawKeyDown theKey
  set the text of me to theKey
end rawKeyDown
```

Don't put this script anywhere else. It might make your stack unresponsive.

What language is your device using? If it is English US, what happens if you change it to English UK (or the reverse, or just change it to either option if you're using a different language)?

Comment: I tried adding your code on the field script but no success. Same with changing the language from English US to English UK.

Comment: In addition to my comment, I tested using my other phone having an android version of 4.0.4 (same with my tablet) and it works fine. could this be because of android version?

Comment: It looks like a bug due to the combination of your LiveCode version and your Android version, perhaps also in combination with your device (and modifications to Android by your ISP). I guess you're out of luck. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The real device keyboard can be a modified version of standard Android keyboard, so its behaviour may vary from device to device.